# Getting the content area to fill the total visible area on "short" pages?

Tags: jquery-mobile

[Using jQuery Mobile version 1.3.2]

I'm working on a jQM project and am running into a bit of a dilemma here. For pages that don't have much content (such as a home page with only 3 buttons on it), and when the footer data-position is set to "inline", there is a big ugly gap below the footer...

[image]

Of course, if I set the footer's data-position to "fixed", then it looks good IF viewed in portrait mode...

[image]

BUT... when it's viewed in landscape mode, it looks bad, as there is barely any room for the content area, due to the header and footer taking up most of the visible area...

[image]

So, my question is... is there a good, working solution for getting the footer to be fixed to the bottom in situations where the content area does not fill up the entire screen, and then have the footer position automatically switch to "inline" for situations where the content area DOES fill up (at least) the entire screen?

OR... alternately... is it possible to have the footer position "fixed" when the device is in portrait mode, and then switch the footer position to "inline" when the device is in landscape mode?

I've spent a few hours researching this online today, but I haven't found any promising solutions to this problem so far (I found a handful of articles / forum posts that addressed the topic, but they were from 2-3 years ago, and the few proposed "solutions" looked like they might create more problems than they solve).

I'm not looking for a solution that is 100% cross-browser (because I know that doesn't exist), but as long as I can find a solution that works well on mobile iOS and mobile Android, I'd be happy.

I would imagine that this would be a fairly popular issue, so I'm a bit surprised that I haven't come across a good solution so far (maybe I just haven't looked in the right place yet).

So.... any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the resize and orientationchange event and then fix/unfix the footer depending on available space.

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/z8U8J/)**

Using script, measure the header height + footer height + content height and compare it to the total window height (viewport).  Then add or remove the ui-footer-fixed class on the footer div:

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page1", function(){
    $(window).on("orientationchange resize", function(){
        FooterPositionFixed()
    });

    setTimeout(FooterPositionFixed, 300);
});

function FooterPositionFixed(){
    scroll(0, 0);
    var totHeight = $(window).height();

    var headerHeight = $("#jqmHeader:visible").outerHeight();
    var footerHeight = $("#jqmFooter:visible").outerHeight();
    var contentHeight = $("#jqmContent:visible").outerHeight();

    if (totHeight > (headerHeight + footerHeight + contentHeight)){
        if (!$("#jqmFooter").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed")){
            $("#jqmFooter").addClass("ui-footer-fixed");
        }
    } else {
        if ($("#jqmFooter").hasClass("ui-footer-fixed")){
            $("#jqmFooter").removeClass("ui-footer-fixed");
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the HTML for this script:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header" id="jqmHeader">
         <h1>My page</h1> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="jqmContent">
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="jqmFooter">
        <h2><a>Go to website</a><br />Copyright<br /> business name</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```